# Getting "object references an unsaved transient instance" on already saved object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `Report` object that has a 'reporter' property.  This 'reporter' is a reference to a `Person`'s ssn that already exists.  When I try and save the `Report` object I am getting "object references an unsaved transient instance" on the reporter property, however this person is already in the Persons table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REPORTS")
public class Report {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="reporter", 
         referenceColumnName="ssn") // <-- Joining to a non-primary key property
    private Person reporter;
    // mutators
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PERSONS")
public class Person {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column(name="ssn")
    private long ssn;
    // other properties

    // mutators
}
```

Here's where I am seeing the Exception being thrown:

```
public ReportTask implements Runnable {
   @Autowire
   private String reportName;
   @Autowire
   private ReportRepository reportRepo;
   @Autowire
   private PersonRepository personRepo;

   public void run(){
      Person p = personRepo.getByName(reportName);  // gets Person Entity by Name
      Report r = new Report();
      r.setName("Report for "+reportName);
      r.setReporter(p);

      reportRepo.save(r);  // <-- Exception is thrown here
   }
}
```

The Exception states that the `Person` Object is transient and needs to be saved before saving the `Report` Object.

Also, to make matters more interesting, it seems the first 89 records insert perfectly fine;  It only fails on the 90th.  I've checked all the values and there is no difference between record 89 and 90...

Comment: The Person instance was retrieved in the same session you tried to save the Report instance?

Comment: I wrapped the method in @Transactional and it's still happening

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full stacktrace of the exception as well as the code of the method reportRepo.save()?

Comment: The `save` method is a Spring CrudRepository instance.  There is no code in the body as it's an interface.

Comment: I've updated the question;  providing details you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into the same issue, I wanted to post what my issue was.  It might help you out as well.

My issue was a `null` field value. It was omitted in my original question because it was for auditing purposes and doesn't play a role in the Objects functionality, however it seems as though if Hibernate sees a `null` value, it treats the Object as a new instance and tries to persist it (or at least it was in my case)